# Triple Integral over a Superquadric

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, proof-writing, volume

How do I solve the following:

$\iiint _V (x^2+y^2+z^2) dxdydz $, where $V=\{x^{2n}+y^{2n}+z^{2n} \leq 1\}$ is a superquadric?

Comment: My first instinct is to apply the change of coordonates $$(u,v,w)=(x^n,y^n,z^n)$$

Comment: ``Superquadrics and Angle-Preserving Transformations,'' Premier issue, cover article, IEEE Computer Graphics and Applications, Vol. 1, No. 1, January 1981.

Answer (score 1):

By symmetry,
$$ \iiint _V (x^2+y^2+z^2) dxdydz=24\iiint_{V^+} x^2 dxdydz $$
where
$$ V^+=\{x^{2n}+y^{2n}+z^{2n} \leq 1, x\ge0,y\ge0,z\ge0\}. $$
Let
$$ x=r^{\frac1n}\sin^{\frac1n}(\theta)\cos^{\frac1n}(\phi), x=r^{\frac1n}\sin^{\frac1n}(\theta)\cos^{\frac1n}(\phi),z=r^{\frac1n}\cos^{\frac1n}(\theta). $$
Then $V^+$ becomes
$$ \bar{V}^+=\{(r,\theta,\pi): 0\le r\le1, 0\le\theta,\phi\le\frac{\pi}{2}\}. $$
Now
$$ \det\frac{\partial(x,y,z)}{\partial r\partial \theta\partial\psi}=\frac{1}{n^3}r^{\frac{3}{n}-1} \sin ^{\frac{2}{n}-1}(\theta ) \cos ^{\frac{1}{n}-1}(\theta ) \sin
   ^{\frac{1}{n}-1}(\phi ) \cos ^{\frac{1}{n}-1}(\phi ) $$
and then
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\iiint _V (x^2+y^2+z^2) dxdydz\\
&=&24\iiint_{V^+} x^2 dxdydz\\
&=&24\int_0^1\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\pi/2} r^{\frac2n}\sin^{\frac2n}\theta\cos^{\frac2n}\phi \det\frac{\partial(x,y,z)}{\partial r\partial \theta\partial\phi}drd\theta d\phi\\
&=&\frac{24}{n^3}\int_0^1\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\pi/2}r^{\frac{5}{n}-1} \sin ^{\frac{4}{n}-1}(\theta ) \cos ^{\frac{1}{n}-1}(\theta ) \sin
   ^{\frac{1}{n}-1}(\phi ) \cos ^{\frac{3}{n}-1}(\phi )drd\theta d\phi\\
&=&\frac{24}{n^3}\int_0^1r^{\frac{5}{n}-1}dr\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin ^{\frac{4}{n}-1}(\theta ) \cos ^{\frac{1}{n}-1}(\theta )d\theta \int_0^{\pi/2}  \sin
   ^{\frac{1}{n}-1}(\phi ) \cos ^{\frac{3}{n}-1}(\phi )d\phi\\
&=&\frac{24}{n^3}\cdot\frac{n}{5}\cdot \frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{2}{n}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)}{2 \Gamma
   \left(\frac{5}{2n}\right)}\cdot\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2n}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{2n}\right)}{2 \Gamma
   \left(\frac{2}{n}\right)}\\
&=&\frac{6}{5n^2}\frac{ \Gamma^2 \left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)\Gamma \left(\frac{3}{2n}\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{5}{2n}\right)}.
\end{eqnarray}
Here
$$ \int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{-1+p}(t)\cos^{-1+q}(t)dt=\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{p}{2}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{q}{2}\right)}{2 \Gamma
   \left(\frac{p+q}{2}\right)} $$
is used.

Comment: The result should be related with Beta functions. Thank you for telling the reference.

Comment: I will calculate when I have enough time.

Comment: Finally, I got the expression.

Comment: I put in an answer by Dirichlet, from Whittaker and Watson. I feel confident about the constants, as it agrees with the result over the round sphere and the cube (limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$)

Comment: @WillJagy, thanks. I will look at the link. Maybe my solution is wrong. I thought it would be easy to handle.

Comment: Worth noting that the Gamma functions and the extra factors of $n$ are the same, it is just a matter of the constant factors. I liked the idea of using the recursion for Gamma to shift to Gamma(1 + something small)  so that things are explicitly bounded. Anyway, just some constants to check

Answer (score 1):

I found an online scan of the first or second edition of Whittaker and Watson, A Course of Modern Analysis. It [includes Dirichlet's method, pages 191-193 of](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Course_of_Modern_Analysis/_hoPAAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover)
See if this works, links to the individual [page 191](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Course_of_Modern_Analysis/_hoPAAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=191), [page 192](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Course_of_Modern_Analysis/_hoPAAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=192), [page 193](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Course_of_Modern_Analysis/_hoPAAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=193).

There was a way to magnify the image, here are the beginning set-up and the final calculation. For the current problem $f=1.$ To take the integral of $x^2$ (on the positive octant) I took
$$ f=1 \; , \; \; \alpha = \beta = \gamma = 2n \; , \; \; a=b=c=1 \; , \; \; p=3, q=1,r=1 $$
Then
$$ \frac{p}{\alpha}  +   \frac{q}{\beta}  + \frac{r}{\gamma}  =  \frac{5}{2n}   $$
so that the one-variable integral on the right is $  \frac{2n}{5} $

For the integral over the whole body of $x^2 + y^2 + z^2$  we get
$$  8 \cdot  \frac{\Gamma \left( 1 + \frac{3}{2n} \right)\Gamma \left( 1 + \frac{1}{2n} \right)^2}{\Gamma \left( 1 + \frac{5}{2n} \right)}  $$
Here I have used the recurrence relation
$$ z \; \Gamma(z) = \Gamma(1+z)  $$
which is 6.1.15 in Abramowitz and Stegun. [Also found it in  the Wikipedia page.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Main_definition)

This gives the correct figure for the sphere ($n=1$) which is $4 \pi / 5.$  It also gives the correct limit as $n$ goes to positive infinity, namely $8$

[image]
[image]

Comment: In your gamma function, where is $1$ from? If there is no $1$ in the gamma function, your answer will be the same as mine.

Comment: @xpaul  I deliberately moved the factors of $1/n$ to match up with the Gamma functions and use $z \Gamma(z) = \Gamma( 1 + z)$ The $n^2$ in your denominator becomes  a constant times $\frac{ \left(\frac{1}{2n} \right)^2 \frac{3}{2n}}{ \frac{5}{2n}} $

Comment: I see now. Thanks.