# Spinning a convex polyhedron

Tags: 3d, classical-mechanics, polyhedra

We all know how easy it is to spin a coin on a table top. With a good twist,
it might spin for 20 seconds or so before wobbling flat.
E.g., [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CUAysaWsdEA&ab_channel=ArtKay).
Let's view a coin as a convex polyhedron.

> ***Q***. What characteristics of a convex polyhedron make it "spinnable"?

I realize this is not a precise question, but still it might have reasonable answers,
for necessary and possibly sufficient conditions for sustaining a stable spin.
For example, I would say the regular tetrahedron is not spinnable, either on its base (too large a friction surface
on the plane/table top), nor on one of its vertices (too unstable).
But perhaps the regular icosahedron is spinnable?
Maybe those with experience with polyhedral game-dice could formulate conjectures.

---

[image]

 
           
[mathsgear](https://mathsgear.co.uk/products/unique-polyhedral-dice)

---

Perhaps every cross-section orthogonal to the spin axis should be centrally symmetric?

The question can be generalized from "convex polyhedron" to "convex body."

Comment: This feels more suitable for [Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Tops spin pretty well and they aren't very different from tetrahedra. However, I don't think this question belongs on MSE.

Comment: In practice I have no trouble spinning tetrahedral die. I believe as long as the center of mass is directly above the single contact point then it will be stable.

Comment: Joseph, if you can stand it, could you please take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3893248/triple-integral-over-a-superquadric ? I suspect this is something you have taught many times. Meanwhile, I imagine there is a physics computation, along the lines of the moment of inertia around the desired spin axis, that would see this through.

Comment: https://architecture.mit.edu/sites/architecture.mit.edu/files/attachments/lecture/Whiting_SpinIt14.pdf

Comment: @WillJagy: "We demonstrate tops and yo-yos that spin
surprisingly stably despite their asymmetric appearance." Nice find, Will!

Comment: I'd like a spinning elephant myself.

Comment: Bächer et al: "We formulate a nonlinear functional that measures the *spinnability* of a solid shape about a user-defined axis."

Comment: @WillJagy: I consider Will's reference to this paper the answer to my question: Bächer, Moritz, Emily Whiting, Bernd Bickel, and Olga Sorkine-Hornung. "Spin-it: optimizing moment of inertia for spinnable objects." *ACM Transactions on Graphics* (TOG) 33, no. 4 (2014): 1-10.

Comment: Well, good. On another note, I was at a market today with a display of Artesian Ice Cream. That can't be right. There are some ice cream parlors in Artesia, California, which shouldn't count